# how to get localstorage items with Selenium JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, testing

I'm trying to get localstorage items with nodeJS and selenium but i'm not able to do it, I tried setting new Item and it was working but it didn't work for getting an item
I'm sure the Key does exist

```
const {Builder, By, Key, Util}= require("selenium-webdriver");
async function example(){

    driver= await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
   // js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
    await driver.get("https://qa-test-digitarm.netlify.app/");
driver.findElement(By.css("input[type='email']")).sendKeys('test@test.com');
driver.findElement(By.css("input[type='password']")).sendKeys('test');

driver.findElement(By.css('.btn')).click();



       // console.log(driver.executeScript("window.localStorage.getItem('is_logged');"));


        driver.executeScript( (function () {
            localStorage.setItem("Id", '{\"_expired\":0,\"_value\":\"133\"}');
           var r= localStorage.getItem("is_logged");
           console.log("test"+r);
        }), );

}

example();
```

Comment: might be in session storage... check your browser's dev tools to check... or try with  var r= sessionStorage.getItem("is_logged");

Comment: trying to get "Id" doesn't work even the "test" doesn't show up, and I'm sure the other key exists I'm checking it from the browser's dev tool

Comment: Seems like the anonymous function is not necessary there... you should just be sending a string to the executeScript method.   If you did enclose that in quotes, it's still just defining an anonymous function but not actually running it.  You'll also want to return a value to use it as you did in the commented line.  (You get it but don't assign or return it... so it won't make it back to your Selenium code...)

Comment: how i can return it back to selenium code, when I try the bellow solution i get Null
driver.executeScript('localStorage.getItem("is_logged")'
         
        ).then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        });

Comment: Use a return statement.  So: retval = driver.executeScript("retval = localStorage.getItem('is_logged'); return retval;");

Comment: im still getting null result on it
retval = await driver.executeScript("retval = localStorage.getItem('is_logged'); return retval;");
       console.log(retval);

Comment: it'll return null if it doesn't exist.  Not sure what's happening there.  Does it work for the "Id" value that you set?  Check case, be sure you are on same domain, check timing issues... (it shouldn't take long for a value to save to localStorage but still takes a certain amount.)

Comment: yes null to for the "Id" :(

Comment: the call has to be made from the same domain/subdomain it was set from.  Check in devtools to see what's listed as the domain there.  (It's possible this value is set from an iframe in a different domain or subdomain... if so, switch the driver to that frame first...)

Comment: I'm not really sure i understand this, but the local storage was set when login is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed the await before clicking the login button to let the browser load the localstorage before getting it just needed to modify the bellow line
 `await driver.findElement(By.css('.btn')).click();`